# Erro ao montar Foreach Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando montar um filtro aonde busco algumas opções do BD fiz um foreach para trazer esses dados do BD mas está trazendo um erro:

**`Trying to get property of non-object`**

Segue meu codigo:

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $categoria = $this->catimage->get();

    return view('administrator.images.index', compact('categoria'));
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
<ul class="simplefilter">
Filtros:
<li class="active" data-filter="all">All</li>
@foreach ($categoria as $categoria)
<li data-filter="{{$categoria ->id}}">{{$categoria ->title}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse erro é no controlador ou na view?

Comment: Esse erro é na View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com [compact](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_compact.asp) não resulta. Faça assim:

Controller:

```
return view('administrator.images.index', ['categoria' => $categoria]);
```

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!

Comment: De nada @BJJ. Ainda bem que deu